# Cake bake is not letting me bake models and does not recognise fields in my tables

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to bake some models that I started this morning, everything was fine then until I had to leave, so I did ctrl^c and exited Putty. Since logging back in everything seemed fine, except when I did `./cake bake` and I got the following errors and warnings:

```
PHP Warning:  SplFileInfo::openFile(/var/www/vhosts/toast.lancs.ac.uk/httpdocs/jahans/Wimbrick/app/tmp/cache/persistent/myapp_cake_core_file_map): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/vhosts/toast.lancs.ac.uk/httpdocs/jahans/Wimbrick/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 355

Warning: SplFileInfo::openFile(/var/www/vhosts/toast.lancs.ac.uk/httpdocs/jahans/Wimbrick/app/tmp/cache/persistent/myapp_cake_core_file_map): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/vhosts/toast.lancs.ac.uk/httpdocs/jahans/Wimbrick/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 355
Warning Error: _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_eng' to File cache in [/var/www/vhosts/toast.lancs.ac.uk/httpdocs/jahans/Wimbrick/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 323]

Warning Error: _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_console_eng' to File cache in [/var/www/vhosts/toast.lancs.ac.uk/httpdocs/jahans/Wimbrick/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 323]
```

I tried using `chmod -R 777` to edit the permissions, but the messages still persisted when I tried `./cake bake` again. Then I tried baking my models anyway, I was able to choose which tables I wanted to bake just fine, but when it asked for my primary key it suggested 0 and after this it gave me the usual "does everything look okay?" message as if everything had worked fine, when I hadn't been able to see my fields, set any validation criteria or do anything useful at all.

Does anyone have any clues?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an external problem at work.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing it wrong.
You need to read the docs on how to execute shells in CakePHP.

Always navigate into your APP dir:

```
cd /path/to/app
```

Then run it relative from there:

```
Console/cake bake
```

Comment: I was doing it from my Console folder. This is the way I've always done it and it's never given me any problems.

Comment: That was never the correct way to do it in CakePHP2.x. That it is now broken is just a logical thing that was going to happen eventually.